# Extrair no R tabelas que ocupam mais de uma página em arquivos pdf

Tags: r

Olá,

Tenho [um pdf contendo uma tabela](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15kP4wMRb12Z0MH9vv3ytcmluA2krQUpK/view?usp=sharing) e eu quero extrair essa tabela para poder analisar no R. Estou usando o *tabulizer::extract_tables()* .

Como a tabela ocupa mais de uma página, ele me retorna um objeto em formato de lista (out) contendo 12 elementos. Em tese, cada elemento é uma parte da tabela. A tabela que eu quero está nos elementos `out[[1]]` até `out[[4]]`

O problema é que como a tabela não tem header em todas as páginas e, imagino eu, também por conta do cabeçalho do documento, a função não consegue delimitar as colunas. O elemento `out[[1]]` tem 4 colunas, `out[[2]]` e `out[[3]]` têm 2 colunas e `out[[4]]` tem uma coluna só. Existe alguma maneira de ao menos eu conseguir retornar esses quatro elementos com quatro colunas?

Código:

```
library(tabulizer)

arquivo <- "1236_Pombos_PE.pdf"
out <- extract_tables(arquivo, output = "data.frame", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

Comment: Tentou controlar usando o argumento `pages`? Pode ser que ele melhore o parse das tabelas

Comment: Oi Tomás, eu gostaria de usar essa função em um loop com 3 mil arquivos, então estava buscando uma solução mais automatizada.

Comment: O problema parece estar na qualidade do PDF. Ai as coisas complicam. Você pode pedir para ver quando paginas o docto tem e depois usar essa informação para parsear cada página separadamente (não sei se isso vai ajudar na qualidade).

Comment: Mas o problema é como transformar as tabelas de 2 colunas em tabelas de 4 colunas. Se você souber manda um `function(x) if(ncol(x) == 4) return(x) else transformacao_necessaria(x)`. Ai depois disso é só empilhar.

Comment: Você tem razão quanto a qualidade do PDF. Eu estou fazendo "a mão" alguns documentos para ver se eu consigo padronizar o tipo de erro, mas em um mesmo pdf cada item da minha lista aparece de um jeito diferente, não parece ter muito padrão não =/

Comment: Que pena. PDF é complicado mesmo

Comment: Um desabafo: ainda vejo instituições dizerem que são adeptas de "dados abertos" apenas por disponibilizar PDFs...